# How can we execute messages at a particular time daily in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to execute the message daily at 10'o clock  5 minutes  25 seconds but I tried the program  I got an error:

```
ERROR OCCURED: 
  throw patterns[5] + ' is a invalid expression for week day';
      ^
 is a invalid expression for week day
```

Code:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('25 05 10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December   Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday ', function(){
    console.log('Time for breakfast');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cron syntax is as described in the node-cron library page:

```
┌────────────── second (optional)
│ ┌──────────── minute
│ │ ┌────────── hour
│ │ │ ┌──────── day of month
│ │ │ │ ┌────── month
│ │ │ │ │ ┌──── day of week
│ │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ │
* * * * * *
```

So, for executing the task every day at 10:05:25, try
25 5 10 * * *

```
cron.schedule('25 5 10 * * *', function() {
  console.log('Time for breakfast');
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: can you tell me the error how to set  username and password using mongodb client  in mongodb program please..see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352662/how-to-set-username-and-password-in-mongdb-program?noredirect=1#comment75707607_44352662